# Directory.GetDirectories() IOException

Tags: c#, directory, ioexception

I have this piece of code which sometimes throws IOException, in its message it says `The file is used by another process` which makes no sense to me at all. I am really confused here. A directory is not a resource that needs to be handled for cross thread operations or sth like that as far as I know.

```
void CloudFolderWatcher_Created ( object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e )
{
    var foldersToCreate = Directory.GetDirectories(e.FullPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    /// do something with foldersToCreate
}
```

What might be the problem here? How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Could it be something to do with `NTFS` (symbolic links or whatever?). And solution is probably do not get sub-folders in one go, but use recursion to handle the case, when certain directory fails with `IOExcpetion`, then just ignore it and continue.

Comment: I you are looking from top level of a HD supress the SearchOption.AllDirectories otherwise you will get an UnauthorizedAccessException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What this means is that some other process (or even your process) holds a lock on one of the directories that prevents your process from enumerating its contents.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a problem behind the FileSystemEventArgs
Because the rest is working.(Supposing  that you use WFA)

Put (A) just above the Public form1()

You will se all the directories under the foldersToCreate variable. Check your "e" arguments

(A)

```
public string Mypath;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        Mypath = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
    if (Mypath != "")
        CheckFOlder();
}

private void CheckFOlder()
{
    try
    {
        var foldersToCreate = Directory.GetDirectories(Mypath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

PS You must add in your form `folderBrowserDialog1`